# how to get notified when zmq protocol error occurs

Tags: zeromq

normally, a zmq socket keeps re-connecting until it is connected. but if it connects to a wrong address, it could stop re-connecting.

one example is that say a zmq subscriber tries to conect to tcp://127.0.0.1:40008, and an echo server is started at 127.0.0.1:40008, this subscriber will connect to this address and then disconnect immediately due to protocol_error, and it will also stop re-connecting, so if later the echo server is stopped and a zmq publisher is started at this address, the subscriber won't connect to it to receive messages.

this is an issue as it happens silently, it's not easy to figure out what went wrong. is there a way to know that a protol_error (or any kind of error) occured inside zmq? or is there a way to make the subscriber reconnects no matter what causes disconnection?

======================update===================================
I think I finally find out the root cause, it's caused by self connection.[tcp self connect](http://sgros.blogspot.com/2013/08/tcp-client-self-connect.html). this issue could be solved by using ports not within the range specified in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range.
and it seems that I already get notified from zmq for this kind of error which is the protocol_error event.
I just didn't know that it means the socket will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `zmq_socket_monitor` to the socket you can get feedback on connection activity including details on why a handshake failed.

I have used this extensively to help debug issues

https://libzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/zmq_socket_monitor.html

`ZMQ_EVENT_HANDSHAKE_FAILED_PROTOCOL` seems like a good candidate for your case

Comment: thanks for the reply,  I did use zmq_socket_monitor, that's why I know the subscriber connected to the address and then disconnected. however, I didn't get the HANDSHAKE_FAILED_PROTOCOL notice. I only get connected and disconnected event.   I only got HANDSHAKE ERROR notice when connecting to incorrect address that doesn't send anything back.

Comment: another thing is that if there is HANDSHAKE event, zmq still does auto-reconnects. won't silently stop.